# Efficient Tree Traversal for simple search

Tags: php, search, recursion, tree, mib

I am using a MIB parser I have written using PHP for a SNMP web interface project I am building.

The node object is in the flowing structure:

```
class MibNode 
{
    public $name;
    public $oid;
    public $type;
    public $status;
    public $description;
    public $canRead;
    public $canWrite;
    public $parent = null;
    public $children = array();
}
```

I am trying to get a node object by it's name.
I have written a recursive function for that:

```
public function getNodeByName($name)
{
    if($this->name === $name)
    {
        return $this;
    }
    else
    {
        foreach($this->children as $child)
        {
            $node = $child->getNodeByName($name);
            if($node != null)
                return $node;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

I have some performance issues with my project, so I have profiled the code, and saw that this function is called ~106,000 times.

Is there any way I can reduce calls to this function, or increase performance?

The full parser code is available [here](https://github.com/AYECKa/WebInterface/blob/development/lib/MibParser.php).

edit: I have profiled the usage of the function using xdebug profile tool, the results are availible [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7493096/callgrind._WebInterface_parse_mibs_php.1430243227).

Comment: That is a lot of calls, but over what kind of usage? A day? Loading the page one time? Also, keep in mind that a recursive function will be called many more times than an iterative function since it may call itself for every child (and will definitely do so if the node is not found). Since one of your questions was how to reduce number of calls, I suppose one answer to that is to rewrite the function iteratively.

Comment: The main goal is to improve the performance, do you think that re-write the function the iterative way can improve that?
Im using this function to build the tree once, and then use the tree and the function to create the webpages, and query the mib for data. (its in use constantly).

Comment: Usually with trees, recursion should be fine. I am not surprised that this function is called many times because of recursion, but it may not be the source of performance problems since each call is essentially just one string comparison and a for loop. Do you have additional evidence that this function is a problem?

Comment: yes, I have used xdebug profiling tool, the results are [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7493096/callgrind._WebInterface_parse_mibs_php.1430243227).

Comment: Sorry, I have zero experience with that tool so I can't do much with those results. About how many nodes are in your tree? Also, you never answered what kind of usage this profile represents.

Comment: Its a ~1-2Mb tree (when using serialize), so I can guess a few hundred of nodes or maybe less.
This profile is on the parse process.
I can upload another web-page render profile if you want
The profiles are viewable with KCacheGrind tool

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76482/discussion-between-bytesized-and-user3700134).

Comment: for some reason I can not replay to chat messages, so I will reply here.
each node contains a short name (about max 20 chars), short description (up to 100 chars usually) oid which is an integer, a type, which can be a small array, or a string, readable and writeable discretes, and refrences. so each node should not be very big...
the data is 1-2Mb but I forgot to mention that it contains some other data. I believe that there shouldnt be more than a few hundreds of nodes in the tree.

Comment: I think ultimately your problem is that you have made many calls to a lookup function that is not optimized in any way. In a binary tree, one child has a smaller value than the current node and one has a larger value than the current node and this is true for all nodes. This means that for each node visited, you can eliminate half the remaining tree from consideration. You are visiting every node looking for the right one, so it may as well be a linked list. Maybe sort your tree or make another sorted lookup tree so you can perform this lookup more quickly. Or use a hash table.

Comment: If you are using `getNodeByName` a lot, it may by worthwhile holding an array of: 'name' to 'node' by reference. That way to can quickly access the correct node. The cost is the extra space for the 'names' array and the building of it.

Comment: the problem is - if I index the whole tree in a key-value data struct, I will lose the ability to perform a lookup on a subtree - which I do often.

Comment: sorry i misunderstood.

Comment: no, the only unique element is the id, which is calculated with the recursive function {parent_oid}.oid